# How can I backup mysql files if system files became readonly in Ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, readonly, database-backups, fsck

FSCK needs to be done and a drive was already mounted.
How can I backup the files since mysqldump is not working because the drive is set to read-only?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You need to back up to some other drive. If you need to fix that drive, it wouldn't be safe to put the backup there.